# Akka - force props serialization upon creation

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I have Akka cluster where actors can be created remotely and locally.

When actor is created it receives initial state (`parameters` in the example below).

I am looking for a method to clone the initial state, because when 2 actors are created locally they are working on the same reference and have race condition (when actor created remotely it received serialized copy of an object).

```
boolean allowLocalRoutees = true;
Set<String> useRoles = Set.of("worker");
ActorRef router = context.actorOf(
            new ClusterRouterPool(
                    new RoundRobinPool(POOL_SIZE),
                    new ClusterRouterPoolSettings(
                            numOfWorkers, maxInstancesPerNode, allowLocalRoutees, useRoles))
                    .props(Props.create(Worker.class, masterRef, parameters
                            )));
```

I found 2 solution which are not good:

1. Use `serialize-creators = on` which is not recommend for prod and this will serialize other actors that don't share the problematic state
2. Create a clone of shared state before the actor is initialized:

   ```
   boolean allowLocalRoutees = true;
   Set<String> useRoles = Set.of("worker");

   Parameters clonedParameters = parameters.clone();

   ActorRef router = context.actorOf(
           new ClusterRouterPool(
                   new RoundRobinPool(POOL_SIZE),
                   new ClusterRouterPoolSettings(
                           numOfWorkers, maxInstancesPerNode, allowLocalRoutees, useRoles))
                   .props(Props.create(Worker.class, masterRef, clonedParameters
                           )));
   ```

   In this solution parameters will be cloned even if it is sent remotely so it is not perfect in terms of performance

Is there any other solution I am missing ?